# jQuery to select the ".html" of <p> with some elements inside removed?

Tags: jquery, selector

For example the original `p` will be:

```
<p>
    <h1>I'm title</h1>
    This is some descriptions.
    <a class="classToExclude">The Link #1</a>
    <a>The Link #2</a>
</p>
```

I just want `$('p').html()` **by excluding the `h1` and `a.classToExclude`**.
Will be looking like:

```
<p>
    This is some descriptions.
    <a>The Link #2</a>
</p>
```

FYI, when i use the selector `$('p').children().each()` method, it is returning just the `nodes` below, not the inner text `This is some descriptions`. It is not included. So i can't use `.children()` selector to loop out.

Comment: The html is invalid and the resulting dom will not have `p` with those children

Answer (score 2):

```
var val = $('div').clone();
$('h1, .classToExclude', val).remove();
var html = val.html();
alert(html);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/7SYFV/63/

.html() doesn't seem to work for <p> element.

Comment: Try http://jsfiddle.net/7SYFV/61/ selector in second line was incorrect for removing h1 elements.

Comment: I edited again. http://jsfiddle.net/7SYFV/62/ ** Now it works but not with `<p>` :(

Comment: Ah I made a mistake, I thought you just wanted to remove the classname, not the whole element. See http://jsfiddle.net/7SYFV/63/

Comment: Yes its ok.. but only with `div` NOT with `<p>` :(

Comment: I think that is a result of what Esailija describes in his comment on your question `The html is invalid and the resulting dom will not have p with those children`

Comment: SO FINALLY, THIS IS WHAT jQUERY CAN'T DO ANYTHING?

Answer (score 2):

Your html is invalid:

```
<p>
    <h1>I'm title</h1>
    This is some descriptions.
    <a class="classToExclude">The Link #1</a>
    <a>The Link #2</a>
</p>
```

Is interpreted as:

```
<p></p>
<h1>I'm title</h1>
This is some descriptions.
<a class="classToExclude">The Link #1</a>
<a>The Link #2</a>
<p></p>
```

In google chrome, firefox and internet explorer.

With valid html like:

```
<div>
    <h1>I'm title</h1>
    This is some descriptions.
    <a class="classToExclude">The Link #1</a>
    <a>The Link #2</a>
</div>​
```

Works just fine when using

```
console.log( $('div').clone().find("h1,a.classToExclude").remove().end().html()) ​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/wVzVB/

Comment: @4lvin `<p>` does not work and is invalid here, why would you use it? `<p>` cannot contain `h1` inside it and it will not work in any browser.

Comment: Why? Because i must. All of thousands of existing pages (in my project) have used `<p>` already. I just need to write a Javascript here. To control something. (Not to touch/modify the existing html.)

Comment: @4lvin your html does not work in any browser so why do you use it? It does not work so there is no reason for using it. If you didn't notice so far that the <p> is actually not working then you can do just fine just by replacing it .

Comment: There is `<td>` above that `<p>`. How about touching that `<td>` above? Any way? I mean, `td.html` can return.

Comment: @4lvin `console.log( $('td').clone().find("p,h1,a.classToExclude").remove().end().html())`

Comment: I still recommend writing valid html, if browser weren't so ridiculously forgiving your sites wouldn't even work and rightly so

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to duplicate the element into an additional jQuery object so that you can use the [`.remove()`](http://api.jquery.com/remove/) function without altering your original content.

To duplicate or clone an element you can use the [`clone()`](http://api.jquery.com/clone/) function.  One you have duplicated your element you can start removing all the un-needed elements -

```
var elementCopy = $("p").clone();
elementCopy.remove("h1, a.classToExclude");
```

`elementCopy.html()` will now contain the elements you want.

---

Note that `$("p")` will select **all** `<p>` elements within your page.  You might want to consider adding some additional classes to your markup to make it easier to pinpoint exactly what elements you want to deal with.